# Child-Theme Category View with modified permalinks (%category% removed)

Tags: php, categories, permalinks, child-theme, plugin-list-category-post

I created a new WP Website and added a child-theme to it. The child-theme contains `header.php`, `footer.php` and I also created a `category.php`, in which I show different headers for each category.

I figured out, that the urls to the projets are now

```
https://domain.com/category/projects/projects-2009/projectname/
```

Now I want to remove the category from the url and i am using the 'standard' trick for category removal in wordpress. In my permalinks i set the actual permalinks structure to

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

and the category base to

```
.
```

The urls are now fine but my `category.php` from the child-theme is not used any more and I also have no articles in the categories. When i change back the permalinks to the default everything works fine.

It also does not work to do it like `category-4.php` for the category with the id `4`.

Maybe anybody can give advice what to do or what the correct way is to handle that.

Comment: It's very possible that the URL you're visiting is not a category archive, but to clarify can you state clearly the URLs and what they're meant to be, as well as what you get instead? There's a lot of implied context that's missing and ambiguity. If it isn't loading the template you expected, what is it loading instead?

Comment: The URL was http://barrierefrei.tolerantes-dinslaken.de/category/projekte/projekte-2011/ before i used the trick and now is http://barrierefrei.tolerantes-dinslaken.de/projekte/projekte-2011/ ... but nothing is displayed anymore

Comment: That URL isn't a category archive, it's a page, specifically the page with the ID 376, child of page 37. Neither of those URLs are category archives. Category archives are what load `category.php`. Not only that, the URL leads to a post of type `page`, that's a page with a page template, it isn't even an archive page. You can tell by looking at the body tag class

Comment: Ok ... but now look at this -> http://barrierefrei.tolerantes-dinslaken.de/category/projekte/projekte-2011/ .... i just set the permalink to its default and it works

Comment: Yes because that is not a page, it's a post archive for a category. Look at the class on the `<body>` tag. You have 2 pages, `/projekte` and `/projekte/projekte-2011`. They have the page ID of 37 and 376. You cannot have those pages and also have this permalink structure, there is a conflict, a clash. They have the same URL, so one wins and the other loses

Comment: Ok ... i see ... so with this structure, how can i remove the word "category" from the URL without loosing this structure?

Comment: You have to remove the pages that have the same slugs/names, pages/posts/archives can't share the same URL

Comment: Tom, i removed the pages, even deleted them from the recycle bin, added the category links to the menustructure and placed the category.php in the child-themes folder. Now the only thing i get is an 404 error for the subcategories for projekte ... for the main category projekte it seems to work

Comment: How did you register your projets post type? Or are those just posts? Or pages? I notice there is no code in your question to debug

Comment: Tom, it are just posts but i solved the problem this morning. I am now using a PlugIn to remove the /category/ from the url and everything works as expected. The category overrides in the child-theme are used and i am working on the category html/css. So thanks a lot, stay healthy and greets from germany, Andy